# Progressive matrix - 3x3 grids with red and blue squares

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

I was told that D was the correct solution, but I can't figure out why.

[image]n here

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere. If so, please [edit] in where you got it from - we have an attribution policy here, and unsourced puzzles may be closed.